# Can't connect via ODBC and FreeTDS to SQL Server using only named instance

Tags: sql-server, odbc, freetds, unixodbc

I already use freeTDS in a project, but connecting to the default instance.

Now I need to connect to a named instance.

I'm able to list all the host instances using tsql, but I'm having issues to connect to the instance.
It's a SQL Server 2016, clustered.

```
# tsql -LH cl04-mssql-sccm
  ...
     ServerName CL04-MSSQL-SCCM
   InstanceName MSSQL_INST_SCCM
    IsClustered Yes
        Version 13.0.1601.5
            tcp 59841
             np \\CL04-MSSQL-SCCM\pipe\MSSQL$MSSQL_INST_SCCM\sql\query
  ...
```

I have the following session in odbc.ini:

```
[ATIVOSDESOFTWARE]
Driver=FreeTDS
Description=AtivosDeSoftware
QuoteID=Yes
AnsiNPW=Yes
Server=cl04-mssql-sccm
Port=59841
;Instance=MSSQL_INST_SCCM
Database=CM_CM3
TDS_Version=7.4
ClientCharset=UTF-8
```

Based on documentation, port and instance are mutually exclusive.
Using port, osql works. Using instance, connection fails with:

```
[S1000][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source
[08S01][unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

On freetds.log I have the following line:

```
login.c:447:invalid port number
```

I have found some similar situations on forums but the solution was always to use the hardcoded port. I want to avoid it.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I've never run into this situation, but have you tried only including the port in `odbc.ini` and not in `freetds.conf`? Or vice versa?

Comment: I'm using only odbc.ini, but tested with freetds.ini and tsql directly with the same results.